# Event listener to the window object that fires when the Storage object associated with the current origin is not changed In IE (Internet Explorer)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage, dom-events, window.location

As per documentation found at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

> "Event listener to the window object that fires when the Storage object associated with the current origin is changed."

but

1. In Internet Explorer listener get called event local storage values are same.
2. In Browsers like Chrome./Firefox/Edge  listener called in other tabs, but in IE its called in source tab itself?

My question is how not not call listener in same tab if values replaced with same values.